# How do you create animated presentation in screencast

Tags: video

Here is a snapshot of the screencast I was watching.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7468116/screencast.png

How do you create such animated presentation in a screencast. I know how to capture stuff I am doing on my computer as screencast but how do you build a dynamic presentations. What are the tools available for a mac user.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm) to do this a number of times.  It's very simple to use and worth the $100.  You can buy it off the website or from [the Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screenflow/id422025166?mt=12).

Also, until 13 May 2011, you can buy it as part of the MacLegion bundle, which means you'd get it (plus a number of applications) for $50.  However, that will be a non-MacAppStore license: http://maclegion.com/

Comment: +1 for ScreenFlow - it's the cadillac/ferrari of tools for this. I would try the free demo and then get it on MAS if you like it for simplicity of updates.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave suggested above I'll use ScreenFlow.  As for animation, I'm not quite sure.  I can't tell from a screencapture.  My guess is that the buttons appeared clicked?  Well, to do this you would created two image files in whatever photo editor you prefer (like Photoshop).  One image would show the buttons not pressed, the other pressed.  On the screencast timeline you would simply put these two images side by side.  When played, it appears clicked (100% feasible in Screenflow).  Hope that helps you.  If not, please describe the animation in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I did not view the linked video but, For very simple animations, I've used keynote: http://www.apple.com/iwork/tutorials/#keynote

There are a couple of very cool, simple things you can do. then export that presentation as quicktime (with a fixed time) and add it to your screencast.